# How to move cursor up, down, left, right in textarea on button press using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, custom-keyboard, textselection

How can I make buttons to move cursor up, down, left or right in a textarea using jQuery?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var clpBrd;
  $("textarea")[0].focus(); /*To show to cursor at the end of text*/
  
  $("#cpBtn").click(function(){
    clpBrd = $("txtOutput").text();
    console.log("COPIED: "+clpBrd);
  });
  
  $("#ltBtn").click(function(){
    var txtVal = $("textarea").val();
    var txtLen = txtVal.length;
    $("textarea")[0].focus(txtLen - 1);
  });
  
  $("#rtBtn").click(function(){
    var txtVal = $("textarea").val();
    var txtLen = txtVal.length;
    $("textarea")[0].focus(txtLen + 1);
  });
  
  $("#upBtn").click(function(){
    var txtVal = $("textarea").val();
    var txtLen = txtVal.length;
    $("textarea")[0].focus( /*??*/ );
  });
  
  $("#dnBtn").click(function(){
    var txtVal = $("textarea").val();
    var txtLen = txtVal.length;
    $("textarea")[0].focus(/*??*/);
  });
  
  var selPressed = false;
  $("#selBtn").click(function(){
    selPressed = !selPressed;
  });
  
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh
}

textarea,
#btnWrap button {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

textarea::selection{
    color:white; background: black
}

#btnWrap {
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#btnWrap button {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="txtOutput">
  Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book.</textarea>
<div id="btnWrap">
  <button id="slBtn">Select</button>
  <button id="upBtn">▲</button>
  <button id="ltBtn">◀</button>
  <button id="rtBtn">▶</button>
  <button id="dnBtn">▼</button>
  <button id="ctBtn">Cut</button>
  <button id="psBtn">Paste</button>
  <button id="cpBtn">Copy</button>
</div>
```

Also how can we select the text using up/down buttons?

If `selPressed` is true then moving the cursor will select the text. Else it just moves the cursor.

Cut/Copy/Paste using array will be difficult I think.

Will I have to use external library like clipboard.js or can this be done without it?

Comment: You should take a look at the [Selection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kindly refer my code, for live demo https://codepen.io/libin-prasanth/pen/dyyjJbG

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var selPressed = false;
  var length = 0;
  var sStart = 0;
  var target = document.getElementById('txtOutput');
  var clipBoard = '';
  // Select click event  
  document.getElementById('selBtn').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    length = target.selectionStart;
    sStart = target.selectionStart;
    target.focus();
    selPressed = true;
  });

  // right button
  document.getElementById('rtBtn').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var textLength = target.value.length;
    if (!selPressed) return;
    length++;
    length = (length <= textLength) ? length : textLength;
    target.focus();
    target.setSelectionRange(sStart, length);
  });
  // left button 
  document.getElementById('ltBtn').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var textLength = target.value.length;
    if (!selPressed) return;
    length--;
    length = (length >= 0) ? length : 0;
    target.focus();
    target.setSelectionRange(sStart, length);
  });

  // down button 
  document.getElementById('dnBtn').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var textLength = target.value.length;
    if (!selPressed) return;
    target.focus();
    length = length + getCharacterPerLine(target);
    length = (length > textLength) ? textLength : length;
    target.setSelectionRange(sStart, length);
  });

  // up button
  document.getElementById('upBtn').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (!selPressed) return;
    target.focus();
    length = length - getCharacterPerLine(target);
    length = (length <= 0) ? 0 : length;
    target.setSelectionRange(sStart, length);
  });

  // copy event 
  document.getElementById('cpBtn').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var text = target.value
    if (!selPressed) return;
    target.focus();
    target.setSelectionRange(sStart, length);
    document.execCommand("copy");
    clipBoard = target.value.substr(sStart, length);
    length = 0;
    sStart = 0;
  });

  // copy cut 
  document.getElementById('ctBtn').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var text = target.value
    if (!selPressed) return;
    target.focus();
    target.setSelectionRange(sStart, length);
    clipBoard = target.value.substr(sStart, length);
    document.execCommand("cut");
    length = 0;
    sStart = 0;
  });
  // paste cut 
  document.getElementById('psBtn').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (!selPressed) return;
    insertAtCursor(target, clipBoard);
    length = 0;
    sStart = 0;
  });

  function insertAtCursor(myField, myValue) {
    //IE support
    if (document.selection) {
      myField.focus();
      sel = document.selection.createRange();
      sel.text = myValue;
    }
    //MOZILLA and others
    else if (myField.selectionStart || myField.selectionStart == '0') {
      var startPos = myField.selectionStart;
      var endPos = myField.selectionEnd;
      myField.value = myField.value.substring(0, startPos) +
        myValue +
        myField.value.substring(endPos, myField.value.length);
    } else {
      myField.value += myValue;
    }
    myField.focus();
  }

  function getCharacterPerLine(target) {
    var w = target.clientWidth;
    var fSize = window.getComputedStyle(target, null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
    fSize = parseFloat(fSize);
    return (w / fSize) * 2;
  }

}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

textarea,
#btnWrap button {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

textarea::selection {
  color: white;
  background: black;
}

#btnWrap {
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#btnWrap button {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="txtOutput">
Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book.</textarea>
<div id="btnWrap">
  <button id="selBtn">Select</button>
  <button id="upBtn">▲</button>
  <button id="ltBtn">◀</button>
  <button id="rtBtn">▶</button>
  <button id="dnBtn">▼</button>
  <button id="ctBtn">Cut</button>
  <button id="psBtn">Paste</button>
  <button id="cpBtn">Copy</button>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 
Can't seem to start selection from the current position of the cursor. Selection always starts from very first word every time...

Comment: The only thing remaining is selection in backward direction...i.e., Left or Up. But it's okay so far too. Works nevertheless...  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to get your current cursor position first like i did in the function `getInputSelection()`

I researched a little bit about moving the cursor position inside a textarea, thanks to [css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/move-cursor-to-end-of-textarea-or-input/), I found a way to move it to the end of the textarea. I adapted this function for your needs. The magic happens in `moveCursor = function(pos)`. You can pass the desired curser position to the fct. Left and right are working totally fine.
Up and down are tricky because the amount of chars in every line changes from line to line.

I decided to put a static value of 100 chars. The curser moves up or down, but the position is not 100 % on point.

I'm pretty sure with a little bit of research you can find a way of count chars per line and optimize this function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var clpBrd;
  $("textarea")[0].focus(); /*To show to cursor at the end of text*/
  
  $("#cpBtn").click(function(){
    clpBrd = $("txtOutput").text();
    console.log("COPIED: "+clpBrd);
  });
  
  $("#ltBtn").click(function(){
     var sel = getInputSelection($("textarea"));
     $("textarea").moveCursor(sel-1);
  });
  
  $("#rtBtn").click(function(){
     var sel = getInputSelection($("textarea"));
     $("textarea").moveCursor(sel+1);
  });
  
  $("#upBtn").click(function(){
     var sel = getInputSelection($("textarea"));
     $("textarea").moveCursor(sel-100);
  });
  
  $("#dnBtn").click(function(){
     var sel = getInputSelection($("textarea"));
     $("textarea").moveCursor(sel+100);
  });
  
  var selPressed = false;
  $("#selBtn").click(function(){
    selPressed = !selPressed;
  });

  
});

jQuery.fn.moveCursor = function(pos) {

  return this.each(function() {
    
    // Cache references
    var $el = $(this),
        el = this;

    // Only focus if input isn't already
    if (!$el.is(":focus")) {
     $el.focus();
    }

    // If this function exists... (IE 9+)
    if (el.setSelectionRange) {

      // Timeout seems to be required for Blink
      setTimeout(function() {
        el.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
      }, 1);
    
    } else {
      
      // As a fallback, replace the contents with itself
      // Doesn't work in Chrome, but Chrome supports setSelectionRange
      $el.val(pos);
      
    }

    // Scroll to the bottom, in case we're in a tall textarea
    // (Necessary for Firefox and Chrome)
    this.scrollTop = 999999;

  });

};

function getInputSelection(elem){
 if(typeof elem != "undefined"){
  var s=elem[0].selectionStart;
  return s;
 }else{
  return '';
 }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh
}

textarea,
#btnWrap button {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

textarea::selection{
    color:white; background: black
}

#btnWrap {
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#btnWrap button {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="txtOutput">
  Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book.</textarea>
<div id="btnWrap">
  <button id="slBtn">Select</button>
  <button id="upBtn">▲</button>
  <button id="ltBtn">◀</button>
  <button id="rtBtn">▶</button>
  <button id="dnBtn">▼</button>
  <button id="ctBtn">Cut</button>
  <button id="psBtn">Paste</button>
  <button id="cpBtn">Copy</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I found these link but was unable to use them... https://jsfiddle.net/tAZSs/ for moving left/right & https://jsfiddle.net/yMUx5/ for selecting text. Any help??